# How to get json data from a file (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, json, object

Just cant figure it out. I have a large object stored as a JSON file and I want to access it once and use it multiple times:

```
var myjson = new Object();
$.getJSON("myJSON.js", function(json) {
  myjson = JSON.stringify(json);
});
$('#console').append(myjson);
```

This does nothing. It's a scope issue, I know. I just don't know how to do what I'm wanting. Must I do all my functions inside the $.getJSON call or is there a way to pass the object that I can use throughout runtime?

Comment: Fyi, you can write `{}` instead of `new Object()`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster. Or just delete it... because you can't use the return value outside the callback.

Comment: Yes, that's better of course - but depending on the other code in the application it might be better to have an empty object instead of `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's a scope issue, I know.

No, it's not a scoping issue. It's an issue with your understanding about how AJAX works. AJAX is asynchronous. This means that when you send an AJAX request, the function that sent this request (`$.getJSON` in your case) returns immediately. It is only inside the success callback that you should use the results. This callback function could be called much later. It doesn't really depend on you at what moment in time in the future this might happen. Might never happen actually if there is an error on your server.

So the only place where you could reliably consume the results that the server sent after an AJAX call is inside the success callback:

```
$.getJSON("myJSON.js", function(json) {
    // here and only here you can access the results of your AJAX call.
    $('#console').append(JSON.stringify(json));
});
```

There are some horrible things that you could do like performing synchronous calls to the server:

```
var myjson = { };
$.ajax({
    url: 'myJSON.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(json) {
        myjson = JSON.stringify(json);
    }
});
$('#console').append(myjson);
```

The `async: false` option makes a synchronous call. Obviously this completely defeats the whole purpose of AJAX as it will freeze the browser during this call. You are probably better of directly including the `myJSON.js` as a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJSON.js"></script>
```

Another benefit you might get from this approach is that the browser will ensure for you that this script is completely loaded before executing any other scripts. So the following could work fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJSON.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myjson = someJavascriptVariableThatYouDeclaredInMyJSON;
</script>
```

and then later:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#console').append(JSON.stringify(myjson));
</script>
```

Comment: You probably don't want to stringify the object again though. Unless you are using IE, you can view objects really nicely in the console - much nicer than a non-prettified json string.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, yes, it's just that the OP seems to be trying to print the JSON in some DOM element with `id="console"` - `$('#console').append(...)`. So I guess he needs *pretty printing* in his HTML and not in the javascript debugging console.

Comment: Ooops, didn't notice it. @philtune: Modern browsers have a console that is much more powerful than a div/textarea/etc. to display debugging data.

Comment: Yep, never did understand synchronous and asynchronous. Is there then a Javascript function for getting a .JSON file and storing the object? Also, how would I be able to see the object in my Chrome console? Didn't realize I could do that w/out stringify.

Comment: @philtune, you could use the following instruction to see the object in your console: `console.log(someObject);`. No need to stringify anything. The console will provide you pretty printing of the javascript object. As far as sync vs async is concerned, I would strongly recommend you reading some AJAX getting started tutorials to understand the difference. Basically it's blocking vs non-blocking call. In a blocking call (sync) you are programming in a sequential way. In a non-blocking call (async) you should use events and callbacks.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, that simplifies the issue. Thank you. Will just save the string in myJSON.js as an object and include it in a script tag. When I'm frustrated and tired I get stupid.